# Distance_of_time_in_words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I am using `distance_of_time_in_words` with the expanded gem [dotiw](https://github.com/radar/dotiw) as follows:

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(@client.report_missing_after.days, Date.today, false, except: ["hours","minutes"])  %>
```

If `@client.report_missing_after` were to equal `7` the code above would return "7 Days" as expected. This works fine if `@client.report_missing_after` equals 1-28, but, when I reach 29 suddenly the output looks like:

```
87847649280000 years and 238878720000 days
```

which is not correct.

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong here. Help?

UPDATE:

Per a comment I simply tried to pass the first argument as an integer and it still doesn't work:

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(29.days ,0, false, except: ["hours","minutes"]) %>
```

Comment: I would say thet they check for 28 days because of feburary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out distance_of_time_in_words works out better when you use it properly and by properly I mean with a timestamp and not a datetime object.

This is what ended up working for me:

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, Time.now+29.days, false, except ["hours","minutes"]) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing in the days explicitly?

```
29.days

var.days
```